# read large txt file using fread from data.table by subsetting with specific columns and rows with condition

Tags: r, fread

I am trying to read a huge( 50 GB) txt file in a server machine but getting a memory allocation error.
Hence I wanted to subset by few specific column names and also get rows with specific ids.
I saw few solutons with cmd and grep command to obtain rows with one criteria but I have multiple criteria

I tried this but failed:

```
patient_id = c("ID1", "ID3", "ID4","ID7")
id = paste(patient_id,collapse="|")
sel_cols = c("colA","colB", "colC")

data1 = fread(cmd=paste("grep",id,"/home/directory/filename.txt"),select=sel_cols)
```

Any help if possible!

Comment: Did you try increasing the memory allocation in `RStudio`?

Comment: At first I tried with column names selection only but got this error: `Opened 46.47GB (49894996933 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 64bit process. There is probably not enough contiguous virtual memory available.
Execution halted`

Comment: If you have enough `RAM` then try increasing memory allocation in `RStudio` to cover `50 GB` using `memory.limit()`.

Comment: Have you tried the bread package?  Claims to use less RAM and is a wrapper to fread.

Comment: memory.limit is not an option as it works only for Windows and I am running my code in slurm.

Comment: package {vroom} might be helpful, too: https://vroom.r-lib.org/